# How do check hit/miss ratio for my Azure CDN (Standard Microsoft) end point?

Tags: azure, cdn, azure-cdn

I'm currently using Azure CDN Standard Microsoft for my website hosted on azure app service.

I'm having trouble in figuring out hit/miss ratio for my end point. could anyone please advise steps/query that can be used to get this info?

Answer (score 0):

An option we use on dashboards is to show request count and byte hit ratio which you can then compare, although the latter may be enough for your case:

[image]

Byte hit ratio is defined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/monitoring-and-access-log) as:

> The percentage of egress from CDN cache, computed against the total egress.
> ...
> = (egress from edge - egress from origin)/egress from edge

E.g. if you have traffic of 100Mb and 25Mb gets served from your origin you'll see 75%, i.e. 75% was served from edge servers.

As with any caching you can control what the edge servers will cache, which the above doc also mentions:

> Scenarios excluded in bytes hit ratio calculation:
>
> - You explicitly configure no cache either through Rules Engine or Query String caching behavior.
> - You explicitly configure cache-control directive with no-store or private cache.